# set cells with specific values as NoData in afloating raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, envi, esri-ascii-raster

I have a raster file which includes floating values. I need to set cells with specific values as Nodata. For Raster integer values, the setnull tool can be applied, is it any tool for floating point?

The image that I have problem with it is the outcome of linear spectral analysis of ENVI software. I imported the image from ENVI to ArcMap by using ASCII to raster tool.

I have tried the Con in the raster calculator of ArcMap but It did not change my image and I got my original image again as output. I need to set the values less than zero to Nodata.

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE! What software are you using/ please update your question and the Tags to reflect the tools you are using

Comment: I note you're saying Specific *Values*, is there a range or list of values that should be null? To set one value is one problem, to set a list or range of values is quite another! We really need to know what software you are using to give any specific guidance.

Comment: AFAIK, `SetNull` works just fine on floating point rasters.

Comment: What syntax did you use with `Con`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you talk about [SetNull](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000007000000.htm) I will assume ArcGis. You will need the Spatial Analyst extension to perform this type of extraction.

Your friends in ArcGis are [Con](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm) and [Extract by Attributes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extract_by_Attributes/009z00000029000000/), this will allow you to specify a clause on what values you want to keep, anything else will be Null.

For example, if you wanted only the parts of a DEM that are above 0:

[image]

The biggest problem is creating an appropriate 'where clause'. For example to extract only a range:
[image]

Con is a bit more powerful when used in [raster calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm), you can use it to set null values or replace values with a constant (or a different raster):

[image]

Will give you a raster that is NoData for less than 215 and the value of the input for values greater than 215.

With both of these tools the output will be the same as the input, so if input is Float 32 then output will also be Float 32.

If you don't have Spatial Analyst you can try the [QGIS raster calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html), which is very much like Esri Raster Calculator or [GDAL_Calc](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html), both will work if you're prepared to learn how to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I have already tried it but It did change my image and I got my original image again as output.

Comment: Please post your map algebra syntax, there is likely to be a logic error that can be addressed.

Comment: I could solve my problem which was about the procedure of exporting the image from ENVI software to Arcmap. Then, i used raster calculator as you have already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression will keep all the values between -1 and 1. The values outside this range will be set to null.

```
Out_Raster = Con((yourraster > -1) & (yourraster < 1), yourraster)
```